# Is it possible to bind list of strings to Action Result Include property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

In in the snippet below

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> CreateAsync([Bind(Include = DataRequestEditProperties)] ComplexModel complexModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await DocumentDbRepository<ComplexModel>.CreateItemAsync(complexModel);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(complexModel);
    }
```

I am *currently* requesting specific JSON properties to be returned for creating a C# razor view the following way :

```
          CreateAsync([Bind(Include = "list", "of", "about", "50", "strings")]
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to declare a list of strings somewhere else and referenced variable set somewhere else? Looking for a temporary solution as I am building a prototype and still defining the models of my MVC project. I would like to define what fields I am requesting in a separate file mapped to a variable that describes the query name and holds the list of strings i need to include

Example of declared variables

```
List<string> DataRequestEditProperties = new List<string> {"bunch", "o", "strings"};
List<string> DataRequestInformativeView = new List<string> {"infoFieldA", "infoFieldB","infoFieldC"};`
```

Comment: The [`Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute.include(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.BindAttribute.Include) property is just a simple string, you could use a `const` string. But if you really have to bind so many properties, perhaps you should have a model with only the properties you actually need?

Comment: If you have "about 50" properties to *include*, perhaps the list of properties to *exclude* is shorter. Can't you use `[Bind(Exclude=...)]` instead?

Comment: @haim770 I was going to suggest that, but I really dislike that option as it allows you to add properties to your model that then go unchecked later on.

Comment: @DavidG. I agree. If over-posting is a security issue, a dedicated DTO is the way to go.